# Multiple table row extend/collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Check my code bellow. When i click More button its display all rows after 6th number. But my goal is to use it on multiple table because the table is generated dynamically on my project. I am having lot of tables so it needs to be work with multiples table. I have tried to use same on two table now when i click on button another table also displays. Whats the solution then for multiple tables?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="headings">
                    <th><h4>Main Cat</h4></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="expendbtn"></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="headings">
                    <th><h4>Main Cat</h4></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="expendbtn"></button>
</div>

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    

$(".table").find("tr").hide().slice(0, 7).show();
$("#expendbtn").html("More");

$("#expendbtn").click(function() {

  if ($("#expendbtn").text() == "More") {
    $(".table").find("tr").show();
    $("#expendbtn").html("Less");
  } else {

    $(".table").find("tr").hide().slice(0, 7).show();
    $("#expendbtn").html("More");
  }

});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made some several mistakes in your jquery:
**1)** As you says all elements will be dynamically generated, so the elements will never get fires the click event, you must use `on()` for dynamic elements.
**2)** Use `classes` for buttons instead of `id`. Id must be unique.
**3)** Use `prev()` method with `this`, wich reference to button, so you will always be in the table wich correspond the button clicked.
**4)** Use `each()` method to iterate over all tables and hide the tr all you need, like you actually have it only works for the first table.
**5)** You arent using [slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_slice.asp) propertly, wich selects a subset of elements based on its index.
Heres the working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".table").each(function() {
        $(this).find('tr').slice(7).hide();
    });
    $(".expendbtn").html("More");
    $(document).on("click", '.expendbtn', function() {
        if ($(this).text() == "More") {
            $(this).prev(".table").find("tr").show();
            $(this).html("Less");
        } else {
            $(this).prev(".table").find('tr').slice(7).hide();
            $(this).html("More");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="headings">
                    <th><h4>Main Cat 1</h4></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info expendbtn"></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="headings">
                    <th><h4>Main Cat 2</h4></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info expendbtn"></button>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is button has the same ID.

**In HTML, `id` attribute must be unique in page**

Use `class` attribute instead.

This should work :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info expendbtn"></button>
<script>
     $(".table").find("tr").hide().slice(0, 7).show();
     $(".expendbtn").html("More");
     $(".expendbtn").click(function() {
         var foundTr = $(this).parent().find('tr');
         if ($(this).text() == "More") {
             foundTr.show();
             $(this).html("Less");
         } else {
             foundTr.hide().slice(0, 7).show();
             $(this).html("More");
         }
    });
</script>
```

> Otherwise, i advice people to use **jquery.Datatable plugin**, it's
>   fantastic ! It contains automatic search field, pagination, ajax loading, and expandable rows like you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should never use an id more than once. The better way to do it is to use a class instead of an id.
Provided in the jsfiddle is a working example.

```
$(".table").find("tr").hide().slice(0, 7).show();
$(".expendbtn").html("More");

$(".expendbtn").click(function() {

  if ($(this).text() == "More") {
  console.log($(this).parent());
    $(this).parent().find('.table').find("tr").show();
    $(this).html("Less");
  } else {

    $(this).parent().find('.table').find("tr").hide().slice(0, 7).show();
    $(this).html("More");
  }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8fzxzcc/1

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `id`s from the more/less buttons and use class (or just rename the ids but still add a class):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-expand">More</button>
```

And use the class as the selector:

```
$('.btn-expand').click(function () {
  var $btn = $(this);
  var $rows = $btn.prev('.table').find('tr');

  if ($btn.text() === 'More') {
    $rows.show();
    $btn.text('Less');
  } else {
    $rows.slice(7).hide();
    $btn.text('More');
  }
});
```

Also, jQuery's [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) creates a new jQuery object containing all the matching elements. So what you're doing is creating a jQuery object with all the rows from all the tables. If that's not what you want, your code should probably be:

```
$('.table').each(function () {
  $(this).find('tr').slice(7).hide();
});
```

```js
$('.table').each(function () {
  $(this).find('tr').slice(7).hide();
});

$('.btn-expand').click(function () {
  var $btn = $(this);
  var $rows = $btn.prev('.table').find('tr');
  
  if ($btn.text() === 'More') {
    $rows.show();
    $btn.text('Less');
  } else {
    $rows.slice(7).hide();
    $btn.text('More');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
      <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
          <th>
            <h4>Main Cat</h4></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-expand">More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
      <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
          <th>
            <h4>Main Cat</h4></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sub cat</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-expand">More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(".table").find("tr").hide().slice(0, 7).show();
$('button').html("More");

$("button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "More") {
    $(this).siblings('table').find("tr").show();
    $(this).html("Less");
  } else {

    $(this).siblings("table").find("tr").hide().slice(0, 7).show();
    $(this).html("More");
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
        <thead>
          <tr class="headings">
            <th><h4>Main Cat</h4></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
        <thead>
          <tr class="headings">
            <th><h4>Main Cat</h4></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sub cat</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info""></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've used jQuery siblings to get the table.
`id` should be unique.

Hope this will help you.